# How to suppress zookeeper logs and copy only the zk response to variable in bash script

Tags: bash, sh, apache-zookeeper

I am trying to fetch a file maintained by the zookeeper using the zkcli.sh but each time there's a zookeeper connection log message printed on the console and we don't have the privilage to change the log level in zookeeper.

For example,

```
#!/bin/bash

file=$(zkcli.sh -zkhost ${zkHost} -cmd get /filepath/file.txt)
```

and whenever this is executed there's a log message printed in the console.

```
INFO  - 2020-07-22 17:30:29.895; org.apache.solr.common.cloud.ConnectionManager; Waiting for client to connect to ZooKeeper
INFO  - 2020-07-22 17:30:29.915; org.apache.solr.common.cloud.ConnectionManager; zkClient has connected
INFO  - 2020-07-22 17:30:29.915; org.apache.solr.common.cloud.ConnectionManager; Client is connected to ZooKeeper
```

How to suppress this log message from the console as well as copy the `file.txt` content into `file` variable?

Comment: `file=$(zkcli.sh -zkhost ${zkHost} -cmd get /filepath/file.txt 2>/dev/null)`

Comment: You should set the logging level from the log4j config file to suppress logging completely and then use `-Dlog4j.configuration=config` when firing zkCli.sh

Answer (score 0):

While you can't completely isolate the file's content without some processing (because of print statements in ZooKeeperMain.java like `System.out.println("Connecting to " + cl.getOption("server"));`), you can significantly reduce the verbosity using an environment variable:

`ZOO_LOG4J_PROP="ERROR,ROLLINGFILE" bin/zkCli.sh -cmd get /filepath/file.txt`

On my default setup (version 3.6.2), the log messages are written to a file under `logs/`. The directory can also be configured with `ZOO_LOG_DIR`.
For more fine tuning, it is also possible to modify `conf/log4j.properties`.